# Safe way to store decryptable passwords in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, encryption

I want to store some keys in an encrypted form in database in a secured fashion. At the same time I need to use the non-encrypted(original) form of the keys somewhere in my code. I planned to use PBKDF2 for password hashing [PBKDF2](http://blog.8thlight.com/adam-gooch/2012/11/04/taking-password-storage-up-a-notch.html). Is it possible to decrypt the key stored in the database in an encrypted form using PBKDF2. Or Is there any simple and secure procedures available?

Comment: Safe and decryptable passwords are an oxymoron. If they are decryptable, they are not safe. If your program can get them in plain form, it does not matter how secure your password store is. (And no, you can't decrypt PBKDF2-generated derived key.)

Answer (score 7):

Passwords and secret keys are usually stored in their hashed form. That means they are processed through a hash function before being saved to the database. A good hash function such as bcrypt has the following properties:

- it produces the same output for the same input
- it produces very different output for different inputs
- its output is not distinguishable from random
- it is **not reversible**

The last property has a very important security implication: when someone gets access to the database, they cannot recover the original keys because the hash function is not reversible, especially when the hash is salted to prevent attackers from using rainbow tables.

That means if you want to recover the keys later on, you have to save them in encrypted (not *hashed*) form. An encryption function has similar properties like a hash function, with the key difference that it is in fact reversible. For this decryption step you need a key, which needs to be stored somewhere.

You could store the the key in your application config but that would mean that if someone gains access to your server, they would be able to retrieve the encryption key and decrypt all the stored keys.

I suggest an alternative approach, which will users allow to retrieve only their own stored keys. It is based on the idea that the keys are encrypted with a user-specific password that only the user knows. Whenever you need to perform an action that needs to store or retrieve the keys, the user is prompted for their password. This way, neither yourself nor an attacker will be able to retrieve them, but your program can access them if the user allows it by entering his password.

- Store a conventionally **hashed** user password in the database e.g. using bcrypt
- Allow users to store additional password with the following procedure:

  - Prompt for user password and keys to store
  - Hash password and compare with database to authenticate
  - Generate salt for each entered key
  - Use user-entered password and salt to encrypt keys to store e.g. with AES encryption
  - Store salt and encrypted keys in database
- To retrieve the stored keys in an action requiring them in plain text form:

  - Prompt for user password
  - Hash password and compare with database to authenticate
  - Retrieve encrypted keys and salt from the database
  - Decrypt stored keys using user password and salt

Be careful to remove user submitted passwords from the application log ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Passwords are never stored in a database in any way that people can decrypt them afterwards. There is no guarantee that someone will not hack your database tables and steal everything that you have stored.

If you store an encrypted (hashed) password for each user, even if your database is hacked, it will take those who stole your decrypted passwords a LOT of time to find out the actual passwords. They can always use your same encryption and compare the resulting hash of common passwords. For example, they can encrypt "MyPassword123" and then compare that hashed password to every password in your database. Weak passwords can still be guessed using this pattern.

Therefore, even non-decryptable passwords have their weaknesses, but if you allow someone to decrypt what you store, then basically it's extremely easy for them to get every single one of your user's passwords. Very bad practice. Some of the biggest and most "secure" companies have had their stored Password Hashes stolen, so you cannot assume you will not be a victim.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: 1. Hashing is **not** encryption, they are completely different things. 2. Brute forcing a hashed password is quite easy to get 90% quickly with frequent password lists and readily available hacking software. 3. Attackers do not need 'every single one of your user's passwords", they just want most, perhaps for sale on the dark web.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this same problem with bcrypt using Ruby where it works for user validation since it compares the difference between a user entered clear text and the hashed password and the hashed password never decrypts to clear text. One of the gems I have found that may solve your problem is **encryptor**, which encrypts using several different keys. So what you can do is to keep your password in the database, while keeping the keys securely in another location (a file in storage).

More information can be found in the [rubygems page](https://rubygems.org/gems/encryptor).

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: The idea is not to keep the key in the database, but in a separate file location say that can only be accessed by service accounts and only a few system admins. Bcrypt and it seems PBKDF2 only solves one particular problem of password validation, but it does not solve the problem when you require clear text password for automated scripts say.

Comment: If clear passwords are required, say to pass on to another application, a better concept is to use a seperate encryption server so the encryption key is not on the DB server but on another minimal very secure server, see this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40598713/451475).

Comment: So how is this different from the method that I have mentioned? I do not endorse saving the keys in the database or on the database server, but a completely separate location that is accessible only by service accounts. Perhaps I've not been too clear in my original answer.

Comment: A separate file location is accessible to an attacker who gains admin access to the Internet connected server, a usual attack vector. A separate encryption server not connected to the Internet with very limited admin accounts and two factor authentication is more secure. The encryption key is not accessible from the Internet facing server. Additionally the encryption server requests should be rate limited  and rate violations should be alarmed. It is close to an HSM in practice. But, by all means do consider using an HSM for password key handling and encryption/decryption of the passwords.

Answer (score 0):

More recent answers to this question:

1. If you're on Rails <7, use [Lockbox](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox)
2. If you're on Rails >=7, [encryption is now built in](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-7-adds-encryption-to-active-record) to [ActiveRecord](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_encryption.html)