# C# store user's sensitive credential data for 3rd party system

Tags: c#, encryption, hash, sha256, rijndael

In our application, I need to ask user to enter credentials such as login, apikey for a 3rd party system, so our application can make API call to that system using the credential. The 3rd party system is using SOAP with login/password, or Oauth using with APIKey to generate token etc.

What is the best practice to store user's sensitive credential data?

Currently I have two databases in different servers, one for storing unique salt value for each client, and another database for storing encrypted data, Rijndael Encryption which is computed with salt values. Every time I want to make API call to 3rd party system, I retrieve data from both databases and decrypted data into credentials to use.

From what I heard, this is not a good practice, password should be hashed not encrypted. but if I hash the credential, the information is lost and I can never restore it for calling 3rd party system.

Comment: You must NOT hash the passwords, as you cannot retrieve them. Your problem is similar to the problem of current web browsers like Firefox etc handling your username and password for the sites you visit. Perhaps you can find some more information on their development pages.

Comment: See this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40598713/451475) for a potential solution where neither the password encryption key is not on the Internet facting server. Kind-of a poor-man's HSM.

Comment: @BernhardHiller I guess Firefox saves login on client browser not on a remote central server, so when central server is hacked, there is no risk to expose millions of client logins.

Comment: @zaph thank you, it looks like a nice solution.